# How can I figure out the duration of hook_block cache time?

Tags: drupal-6

My question is how can i figure out the duration of hook_block cache time and then how can I control it?
I want to control the cache settings to get cached every one hour or two hours?

Any idea about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the Block Cache Alter module for that (http://drupal.org/project/blockcache_alter).

Comment: I have just installed this module but how could I set the time for the caching as there is no option for setting the cache time.

Comment: This module requires that you apply some patch to core. Please read the README file of the module. Without applying the patches, you can configure the cache settings per block (only the settings available from core, no custom settings). The settings are available in the block's configuration page (admin/build/block/list and from there click configure link against the individual blocks).